# String to time conversion issue in python

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

This is my code - I want to convert a string into a time in Python - it sort of works:

```
import datetime
firstTime = ("18:08:14")
firstTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstTime, "%H:%M:%S")
print (firstTime)
```

The problem is, I get '1900-01-01 18:08:14' instead of just '18:08:14'. I know this is a fairly basic thing, but I'm new to Python and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want a `time` object, not a `datetime` object.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date=datetime.now()
>>> date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
'23:55:17'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

As my comment suggests, use a `time` class rather than `datetime` since you don't need the date part:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> firsttime = datetime.strptime('18:08:14','%H:%M:%S')
>>> print(firsttime)
1900-01-01 18:08:14
>>> print(firsttime.time())
18:08:14
```

or simply:

```
>>> firsttime = datetime.strptime('18:08:14','%H:%M:%S').time()
>>> print(firsttime)
18:08:14
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code seems fine. Just change strptime to strftime.

```
import datetime
firstTime = ("18:08:14")
firstTime = datetime.datetime.strftime(firstTime, "%H:%M:%S")
print (firstTime)
```

**strptime** takes a string and convert to datetime object.
**strftime** creates formatted string from given date,time,datetime object according to a specific format